# Does all peer node keeps all users public key in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I know that a user must get an identity created by Certificate Authority(CA) before they join Hyperledger Fabric Network. The CA will create a public key and a private key to the user. When the user submits a transaction to the peer node in the network, the transaction will be signed using private key of the user and the peer node will confirm the transaction by using the public key of the user to confirm the transaction is initiated by a user that had gone through CA first(Correct me if my understanding is wrong).

For example in a network there is OrgA, Org B and Org C. Org A has 100 peer nodes and 1,000,000 user. If each of those 100 peer nodes has to keep 1,000,000 user's public key, isn't it kind of a waste of database resources because each of them has to keep those 1,000,000 user's public key and information when most probably they could divide the keeping of public key since these peer nodes are from the same organization?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate has public key in it. Peer Node does not need to store public key tho, it has to trusts the RCA (Root Certificate Authority) cert. If the cert of a user is generated by the trusted CA, the user's cert is trusted. So the peer node can use the public key on the cert to verify transaction.

Answer (score 0):

User will get identity(digital certificate) to be used in the network from Certificate Authority(CA). CA will use its private key to create digital certificate for the user. If peer node keeps CA's public key, they can verify the validness of the digital certificate. Thus, each peer node doesn't need to keep all public key of the user.

Here's a link about the production of digital certificate. I think this flow works the same with Hyperledger CA.

http://docs.blueworx.com/BVR/InfoCenter/V6.1/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wvraix.voip.doc%2Fq009870_.html